# Detecting outliers in time-series data

Tags: python, time-series, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have some usage data that is structured like this:

```
Date and Hour | User  | Actions
2023-01-01 00 | user1 | 100
2023-01-01 00 | user2 | 50
...           | ...   | ...
```

It's crucial to identify the extreme values in the number of actions for each user. The majority (>90%) of the users have the data distributed non-normally, with no seasonality (etc.). Also, >50% of users have less than 50 data points (they perform some "actions" sporadically).

So I've been looking for a way to identify outliers for each user separately, but different approaches have their critical flaws. For example:

1. Z-Score - either false outlier identification, or missing spikes because of other extreme values;
2. MAD - same here;
3. IQR - performs better, but isn't as accurate as I would like it to be;
4. ARIMA - doesn't appear to be the best choice since it needs to be adjusted for each user separately to get the best results, and also many of them don't have enough data points for the model to work efficiently.

Maybe I'm missing something, and there's an efficient way to work with such data to detect the outliers. I would really appreciate it if you could share your experience, or any helpful recourses on how to implement outliers detection in Python!

Thank you beforehand!